# Linq to update a collection with values from another collection?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have `IQueryable<someClass>` baseList

and `List<someOtherClass>` someData

What I want to do is update attributes in some items in baseList.

For every item in someData, I want to find the corresponding item in baselist and update a property of the item.

someOtherClass.someCode == baseList.myCode

can I do some type of join with Linq and set baseList.someData += someOtherClass.DataIWantToConcantenate.

I could probably do this by iteration, but is there a fancy Linq way I can do this in just a couple lines of code?

Thanks for any tips,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To pair elements in the two lists you can use a LINQ join:

```
var pairs = from d in someData
            join b in baseList.AsEnumerable()
                on d.someCode equals b.myCode
            select new { b, d };
```

This will give you an enumeration of each item in `someData` paired with its counterpart in `baseList`. From there, you can concatenate in a loop:

```
foreach(var pair in pairs)
    pair.b.SomeData += pair.d.DataIWantToConcantenate;
```

If you really meant set concatenation rather than `+=`, take a look at LINQ's Union, Intersect or Except methods.

Answer (score 14):

LINQ is for *querying* - not for updating. That means it'll be fine to use LINQ to find the corresponding item, but for the modification you *should* be using iteration.

Admittedly you might want to perform some appropriate query to get `baseList` into an efficient form first - e.g. a `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>` based on the property you'll be using to find the corresponding item.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the `IQueryable<SomeClass>` into a `List<SomeClass>`, use the `ForEach` method to loop over it and update the elements, then convert back to `IQueryable`:

```
List<SomeClass> convertedList = baseList.ToList();
convertedList.ForEach(sc =>
{
    SomeOtherClass oc = someData.First(obj => obj.SomeCode == sc.MyCode);
    if (oc != null)
    {
        sc.SomeData += oc.DataIWantToConcatenate;
    }
});

baseList = convertedList.AsQueryable(); // back to IQueryable
```

But it may be more efficient during this using non-LINQ constructs.

Comment: would it work to do a cross between this approach and the accepted approach, e.g. 
(from d in someData 
 join b in baseList.AsEnumerable() on d.someCode equals b.myCode 
 select new { b, d }).ToList.ForEach(a=>
{
a.b.SomeData+=a.d.DataIWantToConcatenate;
});

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, it should be a combination of loop and LINQ

```
foreach (var someDataItem in someData)
{
    someDataItem.PropertyToUpdate = (baseList.FirstOrDefault(baseListItem => baseListItem .key == someDataItem.key) ?? new SomeClass(){OtherProperty = "OptionalDefaultValue"}).OtherProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply find objects that are in one list but not the other, because they are two different types. I'll assume you're comparing a property called OtherProperty that is common to the two different classes, and shares the same type. In that case, using nothing but Linq queries:

```
// update those items that match by creating a new item with an
// updated property
var updated =
    from d in data
    join b in baseList on d.OtherProperty equals b.OtherProperty
    select new MyType()
    {
        PropertyToUpdate = d.PropertyToUpdate,
        OtherProperty = d.OtherProperty
    };

// and now add to that all the items in baseList that weren't found in data
var result =
    (from b in baseList
     where !updated.Select(x => x.OtherProperty).Contains(b.OtherProperty)
     select b).Concat(updated);
```