# Update List<T> using foreach loop and Condition using LINQ/LAMBDA

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this

```
foreach (var item in SeasonList)
{
    if (item.Text == "ALL")
    {
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's stopping you?

Comment: i want to do The looping and conditioning using LINQ/LAMBDA

Comment: @user2032722: No, you don't. I already explained why in my answer to your last, similar question.

Comment: You can't modify the collection you're iterating over using Linq. You can transform a list and merge the results.

Comment: @Romoku: But you can modify the objects inside a list while enumerating! That's an important distinction.

Comment: Why this unnecessary urge to use linq? It's like the new regex of our age - have a problem? Solve it with linq!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, however, it doesn't buy you anything in this case since it's a simple iteration.

Comment: @Romoku: I don't follow. The OP doesn't want to change the list. He simply wants to change the properties of the items inside the list.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes and using linq isn't going to buy you anything in this case. I could see using a `Where` to filter the list, but that's about it.

Comment: @Romoku: Yeah, well, that's what I am saying all along. See also my answer in the duplicate...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in SeasonList.Where(x => x.Text == "ALL"))
{
    item.Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Simple, understandable, good use of LINQ and foreach (yes, it's possible to write loops with LINQ!), +1.

Comment: Agreed. Let's play fair, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 9):

This may work also, but in my opinion, what you did is already good.

```
SeasonList.ForEach(s => s.IsSelected = s.TEXT != "ALL");
```

Or, to match exactly initial requirements :

```
SeasonList.Where(s => s.TEXT == "ALL").ToList().ForEach(s => s.IsSelected = false);
```

Comment: FYI, this is not entirely correct. This will _also_ set `IsSelected` to `true` when `TEXT == "ALL"`; the original code _only_ set entries to `false` and did not modify them otherwise (though I'll bet that this is the correct intent)

Comment: I think still not proper, OP does not want to change IsSelected if item.Text is not "ALL"

Comment: You are right, I missed this implementation detail. Another edit then.

Comment: its working ...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair how will this set `IsSelected` to `true` when `TEXT == "ALL"`? Update: I see now that OP changed the question, originally your statement made sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemObject> items = new List<ItemObject>()
        {
            new ItemObject() { Text = "Text 1", IsSelected = true },
            new ItemObject() { Text = "Text 2", IsSelected = true },
            new ItemObject() { Text = "ALL", IsSelected = true }
        };

        items.ForEach(x => { if (x.Text == "ALL") x.IsSelected = false; });
    }
}

class ItemObject
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SeasonList.ForEach(q => q.IsSelected = q.Text == "ALL" ? false : q.IsSelected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update using index

```
        var index = SeasonList.FindIndex(x => x.Text == "ALL");
        if (index > 0) SeasonList[index].IsSelected = false;
```

Another option

```
      foreach (var item in SeasonList.FindAll(x => x.Text == "ALL"))
        {
            item.IsSelected = false;
        }
```

Note:

Check Jon Skeet's answer [LINQ is for querying - not for updating.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160903/linq-to-update-a-collection-with-values-from-another-collection)