# How to make a foreach loop skip the item upon exception

Tags: c#, .net

How to make a foreach loop skip the item upon exception?

```
foreach (var item in items) 
{
   newItems.Add(new object
   {
      Name = item.name,
      Category= GetCategoryByName(item.name),
      AddedTime= DateTime.Now
   });
}
```

Let's say that in my List of items, I got 1000 objects,
Each time I create a new object, I call for a function that looks up in a list and retrieves the categoryName by doing

```
private string GetCategoryByName (string name) 
{
   return CategoryList.Where( n=> n == name).First();
}
```

But it happens that the name doesn't exist in the Category list, which will cause an exception that no sequence match e.g.

What I wonder then is how can I just skip this item that doesn't exist in the category list? What I would like to do is to log the Name that doesn't exist in the CategoryList and continue to the next item. It feels like when the exception occurs on f.eks item with index 600, it just stops there and exits the foreach loop, with only 599/600 items. When it should continue and end up with 999 items (since one caused exception).

How can I fix this? I want to log and ignore all the items that causes exception due non-existent categoryname when looking up in the category list.

Comment: Where is the `name` variable coming from in your code?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead and check for `null`. `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` of name not found.

Comment: But I don't want it to be null, I just want it to skip the item, since it is required to have the category name to be added to the list. Any suggestions? @Fabio

Comment: @iSpain17 Corrected it.

Comment: You should avoid coding by exception - especially when you have such an easy way to avoid using them.

Comment: So use FirstOrDefault and then you can check if the name is null, if it is you can skip adding to result list, tada!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update List<T> using foreach loop and Condition using LINQ/LAMBDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729973/update-listt-using-foreach-loop-and-condition-using-linq-lambda)

Comment: Where do I  add the exception handler since it is null?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `newItems` is a `List<object>()` then you can do this:

```
newItems.AddRange(
    from item in items
    join category in CategoryList on item.name equals category
    select new
    {
        Name = item.name,
        Category = category,
        AddedTime = DateTime.Now
    });
```

---

Now, just in case `CategoryList` contains duplicates, then this is more in keeping with the original code:

```
newItems.AddRange(
    from item in items
    from category in CategoryList.Where(n => n == item.name).Take(1)
    select new
    {
        Name = item.name,
        Category = category,
        AddedTime = DateTime.Now
    });
```

---

To get the items that should be logged, do this: `items.Where(item => !CategoryList.Any(n => n == item.name))`.

Comment: OP needs collection of names not existed in category list as well, for logging

Answer (score 2):

I suggest computing `category` *before* adding a new item:

```
    foreach (var item in items) {
        string category = CategoryList
          .FirstOrDefault(n => n == item.name);

        if (null == category) // we don't have category
            continue;

        newItems.Add(new object
          {
              Name      = item.name,
              Category  = category,
              AddedTime = DateTime.Now
          });
    }
```

Comment: You don't need `.Where()`, you can put the predicate in `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @iSpain17: you are quite right, thank you! `Where` is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
foreach (var item in items) 
{
    string catName = GetCategoryByName(item.name);

    if (catName != null)
    {
        newItems.Add(new object
        {
            Name = item.name,
            Category = catName,
            AddedTime = DateTime.Now
        });
    }
}
```

And fix

> GetCategoryByName

to:

```
private string GetCategoryByName(string name) 
{
    return CategoryList.FirstOrDefault(n => n == name);
}
```