# WPF ObservableCollection : possible to modify one particular property on all items at once?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I got an ObservableCollection (Zone class contains a IsFiltered boolean property) on which several items got theirs IsFiltered property set to true.
For a few cases, I need to unilateraly remove all filters (i.e. set IsFiltered prop to false for all ObservableCollection items).

Is there a way to achieve this the way ObservableCollection.Single(LINQ request) do it, or do I have to loop on my ObservableCollection to set this prop to false on all items?

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to loop but at least restrict your loop to the objects that need resetting:

```
foreach(var zone in zones.Where(z => z.IsFiltered))
{
     zone.IsFiltered = false;
}
```

As other answers/comments have mentioned, avoid Linq for the update. See Jon Skeet's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1160989/1202600 - Linq is for querying, not updating.

Comment: No problem, I've corrected my Where clause as noticed it was wrong when you commented! :)

Comment: I saw and corrected in my code ;). In that way, could you please merge the "for each" in "foreach" and add the last missing bracket? I tried to but SO said that only 6+ char mofifications are allowed. Just to let people copy.paste without updates. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Lists in C# got ForEach method which kind of does what you want, so:

```
myObservableCollection.ToList().ForEach(x => x.MyFlag = false);
```

Comment: It is essentially the same thing as just a `foreach` loop, but with one downside; you're iterating it twice.

Comment: Good point, but since it's done on ObservableCollection object we may assume that this collection is used as a collection for objects displayed on the user interface. If there would be so many objects in the collection, that it could be a performance problem, then the bigger issue would be probably displaying it to the user - not only from performance issues, but more because people won't be simply able to use interface with too many of those items displayed on it.

Comment: That might be true, but I would advice against `.ForEach(...)` anyway, because this syntax should be reserved for Expressions, unfortunately it exists, but adds no real value. You could easily read `ForEach(x => x.MyFlag == false);` But that is just an opinion ;)

Comment: @Amby - what about water on Mars? Question was not about thread safety, but if it's possible to do an update in a func style way. You can't access observable collection from other thread that the one owning it and it's quite obvious for anyone who ever did multi thread wpf app.

Comment: @ChrisW. : thank you, this was originally where I headed on... But as comments said it seems to be less optimized in performance terms. At least now I know about this ForEach() ;)

Comment: @nbonniot - as long as you are not building software where milliseconds are priceless, then this should not be a performance concern. But if you do, maybe you should think rather of C or C++ instead of C# ;) good luck with your project. I also learned something new thanks to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my thoughts (since you haven't accepted any answer as yet - please consider if you have moved on)

There is no other way than iterating through 'ObservableCollection'. You may find APIs (linq) to do that for you, but in the end it has to iterate through all objects to update their state.

If your collection is updated by other threads then you need to consider thread safety also (it will through exception if other thread updates while you are iterating to update IsFiltered)

Other point is updating a property doesn't reflect in binded UI unless that property raises 'NotifyPropertyChanged' event. So your object should have something like below:

```
public bool IsFiltered{
get { return _isFiltered; }
set {
    if (_isFiltered == value) return; //no need to modify and trigger UI update
    _isFiltered = value;
}
```